# A genus equivalence issue for ternary forms

Tags: quadratic-forms

I am trying to understand the definition of the genus equivalence (semi-equivalence) for positive definite ternary forms. I recognized that there are some (serious) issues in the literature, and I was confused. To ask my question, I need some conventions:

Let $q(x,y,z)=ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dyz+exz+fxy$ be a positive definite, primitive ternary form. Here $q$ is defined Watson's sense. So by a primitive form, I mean the $\gcd(a,b,c,d,e,f)=1.$

In Gauss, Smith, Dickson's sense, it is a ternary form if $d,e,f$ are even. So, the definition of a ternary form and a primitive form are different from Watson's sense.

Since Smith assumed that $d,e,f$ are even number, we cannot directly use his results to check when two (primitive) ternary forms in Watson's sense are genus equivalence.

My question is as follows: Is there a way to extend his results to any ternary forms in Watson's sense? More explicitly, given two primitive ternary forms (in Watson's sense) can we decide whether they are genus equivalent or not by checking their assigned characters?

For example, there is a very nice (unproven!) result in Lehman's paper (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2153043?seq=1), which is Proposition 4 in page 410. He used Watson's definition for ternary forms, and stated this result in Watson's sense. However, he does not prove this very nontrivial fact, and he only gave references. One of the references he gave there is Dickson's book. But Dickson's definition for ternary forms is different as I said above. So it requires many arguments to use this reference (in my opinion). If Lehman's result was true, it would be great. I tried to prove Lehman's result, but it seems extremely hard. I hope I could explain my issue clearly. My question is again that are there any (proven) results as Lehman's one related to my question? Or can anyone see how we can prove Lehman's result?

As a note, I stated there are some issues in the literature because I heart from a Professor (who is expert about the theory of the quadratic forms) that he has counterexamples for both Lehman's the aforementioned result and Dickson's result related to this topic.

Comment: well, incase the person asking was not you, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389721/computing-the-genus-of-certain-ternary-indefinite-lattices/391826#391826  with reference https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Edrm/manuscripts/eiqf.pdf   Perhaps you are aware of the increasing popularity of the way Conway wrote things in quadratic forms, despite the lack of proofs at the time. The main reference of Lehman is SPLAG  pages 378-384. I think you also mentioned Hanke;  I suspect that either his adviser (Shimura)  or he  proved Conway's notation for the Mass Formula.

Comment: see also   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70666/lorentzian-characterization-of-genus, which was about the characterization of genus on page 378  of SPLAG, that two forms are in the same genus if and only if the direct sums of the forms with the hyperbolic plane are integrally equivalent. Probably worth learning  how to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I will study the paper which you shared. Yes, you are right that Lehman gave a reference in SPLAG in the result which I mentioned above. But he also gave references Dickson's book. That's completely hand-waving argument. Even the definition of the ternary forms is not the same. This is huge because the biggest problem/job in the genus equivalence issue is even prime. 

Your first link is related to the indefinite forms. I think that is also very different from the definite case...

Comment: Thanks also for your second comments. Yes, I know that characterization. I tried to prove it also. My supervisor has a proof for it. But I don't see its relevance with my questions.

Comment: Harun,  I would like to see Kani's proof of the Lorentzian characteristic. If he has some sort of notes  available....  Meanwhile, you have not mentioned Siegel's  simple characterization of genus. Two forms are in the same genus if they are rationally  equivalent without essential denominator. That is, the Hessian matrices $A,B$  have integer matrices $P,$   where $P^T A P = k^2 B$  and $\gcd(k, \frac{1}{2} \det A) = 1 .$  And the other order, matrix $Q$

Comment: Whenever his proof is available, I can share with you. Yes, I know that characterization. I thought it was introduced by Smith in 1867. I actually used that characterization above implicitly. By Theorem 50 of Watson's book and that characterization, we can connect the old definition of the genus equivalent with the modern definition which was given in terms of $p$-adic integers.

Comment: For what it's worth, I helped Pete L. Clark with an article, I wrote a section using Lorentzian form of the genus , starting about page 25. My main source was Ebeling.   http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Clark_Jagy_11_13_2013.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your work. It seems interesting. I will share it with my Professor and probably study its some points. If I have some questions or comments, I will let you know.

Comment: Here is the key points of Kani's proof for the fact we discussed: The key points can be also found in Remark 27 of the paper 'Jacobians isomorphic to a product of two elliptic curves and ternary quadratic forms'. 
First of all, note that xy is universal, so xy-q is universal. Then the class number of xy-q is 1 by Theorem 1(iii) of Watson's paper, namely The equivalence of quadratic forms. Then the hardest part follows. The other part is easy and also can be found in Corollary 26 of Kani's paper.

Comment: Harun, thanks. Where (and when)  did Kani's article appear?

Comment: Here is the link for the article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X14000213